# PHP - is it safe?

Tags: php, web

i got a php page like this

```
<?php
if (!$_COOKIE['password']=="123") {
    header("location: https://google.com");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
very sensitive data that i don't want anyone to look at
</body>
</html>
```

i know putting the password in a cookie non-encrypted like that isn't safe the point here if the password in the cookie isn't 123 can the visitor access the "very sensitive data"????

Comment: You should `exit;` after the `header()` call to prevent the script from continuing execution.

Comment: you should also use `!isset($_COOKIE['password']) || $_COOKIE['password'] !== "123"` to void any isset warning that might push to the browser if the cookie is not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is safe in saying that the user will not see the sensitive data if the password doesn't equal `123`.

however I would change the if statement to

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['password']) || $_COOKIE['password'] !== "123"){

    header("location: https://google.com");
    exit;

}
```

This simply does better checking as well, the `exit` makes sure to kill the page afterwards so it makes sure nothing else loads just incase.